# Share parameters between WebLogic portlets

Tags: parameters, portlet, shared, weblogic-10.x

As usual, i come to you with an issue i can't solve about portlets on WebLogic....

So.. I have two portlets running on the same page. My portlet needs to take a parameter from url(AES or blowfish encrypted), decrypt it, then send a request to a WS with the value. Which does. Additionally, i need to have this value sent to the other portlet (log in portlet) for it to know if he should skip a certain step or not.
So.. Long story short, i need to find a way to send this value, not in the url(as it needs it decrypted and i can't show it), but maybe in a session visible by all portlets. A quick way would be in a cookie, but cookies can be too easily hacked.. I've tried using APPLICATION_SCOPE but the other portlet can't see it.

Set it like

```
session.setAttribute("myval", myval, PortletSession.APPLICATION_SCOPE);
```

Then get it in the other portlet with

```
session.getAttribute("myval",PortletSession.APPLICATION_SCOPE);
```

I've looked over how APPLICATION_SCOPE should work, read about shared parameters, but couldn't really find something to fit my need. I'm kind of stuck so i decided to ask. Maybe you guys can help.

http://portals.apache.org/pluto/portlet-1.0-apidocs/javax/portlet/PortletSession.html

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mydeveloperworks/blogs/Joey_Bernal/entry/portlet_session_scope_and_sharing?lang=en

Regards !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got over it. It seems that i was making the call in a wrong place so the attribute didn't get in the session from doView where i needed it. The answer for shared parameters is, indeed, APPLICATION_SCOPE.

Thanks!